# EarlyStopping in GridSearch - how to get the mean epoch after which training stopped?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

is there a way to get the mean number of epochs when training stopped by EarlyStopping in GridSearch?

```
grid = GridSearch(estimator=model, param_grid=params, cv=10, scoring='accuracy', refit='acc')

results = grid.fit(X, y, epochs=200, valiation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)])
```

Something like that:

```
for mean, stdev, param in zip(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_acc'],
                          grid.cv_results_['std_test_acc'],
                          grid.cv_results_['params'],
                          grid.cv_results_['mean_epochs' ?????
```

Many thanks for every hint

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: @BillChen I'm using Keras and scikit-learn

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. But just maybe this answer to what I believe to be a related or similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874596/how-to-detect-the-epoch-where-keras-earlystopping-occurred) helps.